# POST data using ajax and then redirect the browser from server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, curl

I have the following server side `CURL` post function.
From the ajax the values are posted to the below URL using curl and i will get response only if there is some error (Like invalid apikey supplied etc..) .

If everything goes well,it should redirect to another success page.The below url has a dynamic form which is posted to another URL when everthing goes well.
But this doesn't redirect the browser.Why is it happening?

IS there anyway I can follow the redirect made by the below URL when using ajax POST?

IF it was a normal form post it worked.The datas are posted to this url and the this url endpoint has a dynamic form which is submitted to another URL where I will be taken to.

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://exampletestdomain.com/js_opencart/submit';
    $curl = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            $json = array();

            if (curl_error($curl)) {
                $json['error'] = 'CURL ERROR: ' . curl_errno($curl) . '::' . curl_error($curl);

                $this->log->write('AUTHNET AIM CURL ERROR: ' . curl_errno($curl) . '::' . curl_error($curl));
            } elseif ($response) {
            }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're sending a request from AJAX, the problem is that the server pushes the result back to you and can't redirect. Pass the redirection url back to client as result of AJAX, then use:

```
window.location.href = url
```

Comment: The redirection is not a ind of pure redirect like,it not a static page to which it is getting redirected.The server is doing a dynamic form post with some datas to a url.Kind of posting data to payment gateway,so it shows the payment gateway page after redirection.

Comment: So, if i understood that correctly, you should **not** send the request via ajax but by a GET anchor (with form) so you could use `header("Location: xx")`